# jquery onhover works, onclick does not

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've added a liking/disliking function my comics website.

I've made custom graphics for it.

- When a user hovers over selection, it will change, then swap back off hover...
- When a user clicks, it will swap images until they click the same vote again, where it will switch back to the original.

[image]

The on hover works, but the on click does not... I'm trying to implement this with Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var images = {
      "like": [
        "./images/SiteDesign/like_hover.png",
        "./images/SiteDesign/like.png",
        "./images/SiteDesign/liked.png"         
        ],
      "dislike": [
        "./images/SiteDesign/dislike_hover.png",
        "./images/SiteDesign/dislike.png",
        "./images/SiteDesign/disliked.png"
        ]);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $("#like, #dislike").hover(function(e) {
                     // mouseover handler
                     if (this.id in images) // check for key in map
                         this.src = images[this.id][0];
                }, function(e) {
                     // mouseout handler
                     if (this.id in images)
                         this.src = images[this.id][1];
                });

                $("#like, #dislike").click(function(e) {
                    alert("clicked");
                    if (this.id in images) // check for key in map
                         this.src = images[this.id][2];
                }, function(e) {
                     // mouseout handler
                     if (this.id in images)
                         this.src = images[this.id][1];
                });                     
            });
</script>
```

Any thoughts? I've even put a alert("clicked") within the click function, but it's not even calling that.

Comment: you are missing a "j" in `Query(document)` ?

Comment: You're sure that the `.hover` *does* fire?

Comment: And click only has **one** function, not two, that's why it's not working, it's not the deprecated toggle() function, or hover()!

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes, it works. click does not

Comment: @adeneo that was a typo, oops

Comment: @adeneo can you please clarify?

Comment: Clarify? You have two function calls in click, there can be only **one**, so remove the last function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$("#like, #dislike").click(function(e) {
      alert("clicked");
      if (this.id in images) // check for key in map
            this.src = images[this.id][2];
}, function(e) {
      // mouseout handler
      if (this.id in images)
            this.src = images[this.id][1];
});
```

with this:

```
$("#like, #dislike").click(function(e) {
      alert("clicked");
      if (this.id in images)
            this.src = images[this.id][2];
});
```

**EDIT:**

In fact, just doing this would be easier :

```
$("#like, #dislike").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       if (this.id in images) this.src = images[this.id][0];
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       if (this.id in images) this.src = images[this.id][1];
    },
    click: function() {
       if (this.id in images) {
           this.src = images[this.id][2];
           $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: okay, it fires now and changes the images... but, when I move my cursor away, the other function "off hover" fires and immediately changes the img src to `images[this.id][1];`

Comment: No. The point is the like image changes on and off hover... but when it's clicked, the image swap is supposed to remain.

Comment: Then you need to change your code! I updated the answer to add a removal off the event handlers, but this stuff is tricky. When you're telling it that it should change the image on mouseleave, it will keep on doing that, regardless of wether or not you decide to click it as well. That's how code works, it does what you tell it to (most of the time), and not always what you'd like it to do.

Comment: lol words of wisdom... yeah it's tricky for me. Thank you. My overall goal is this... when a user "likes" a comic, the image will change to a green shirt... (See above)... but if they click "like" again, it will change back to the white shirt... or if they've liked it, but then click on dislike... it will make the "like" shirt white again, and the "dislike" shirt red. (my liking script will then remove the like from the db)

Comment: Yes, I think I get what you're trying to do, but that's the tricky part. I would consider starting over, and use classes for the images with backgrounds etc. That way you can set the "clicked" class to have higher priority than the "hover" classes, and that way it would'nt change when hovered after a click etc. It would also make it possible to do the whole hover thing with CSS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25485/discussion-between-growler-and-adeneo)